# Setting window state takes away the keyboard focus

Tags: wpf, window, lost-focus, windowstate

We have an application which has multiple windows. One of the window is a notification window which pop-ups and closes by its own based on certain condition. We want the window to come in front of all the windows and should not take away the focus.
So we have set the **Topmost** property to true and **ShowActivated** to false. We are also setting the **WindowState** property of the window to **Normal** each time the window opens so that it always come up in front even when the user has minimized the window.

So in some system this behavior works fine while in some of the systems the focus is lost.
The behavior is intermittent in nature.

If we don't set the window state then the focus is not lost and this works fine.
But we are not sure that how is the focus preserved in some of the system even after setting the window state property ?